# Python Adding +1 to a list item cointained in a dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

First, I have a list of dicts with the info of some athletes which looks like this:

```
athletes = [{"name":"Robert", "country":"england", "event": "athletics men's 50000 metres", "medal":"gold"}, 
{"name":"Jan", "country":"england", "event": "athletics men's 50000 metres", "medal":"silver"}....]
```

I need to create a dict based on the name of Robert's country and the number of medals they (the country in a specific event) have obtained, it should look like this:

`{'canada': [0, 0, 1], 'china': [1, 0, 0]...}`

The first position represents gold medals, second, silver and third bronze.

{"medal":} can have "gold", "silver", "bronze" or "na" (not applicable)

I've tried doing this:

```
def funct(athletes:list, event:str):
    import copy
    list1 = [0, 0, 0]
    dicc = {}
    for i in athletes:
        if i["event"] == event and i["medal"] != 'na':
            dicc[i["country"]] = copy.deepcopy(list1)
        for country in dicc.keys():
            if country == i["country"] and i["medal"] == "gold":
                dicc[country][0] +=1
            elif country == i["country"] and i["medal"] == "silver":
                dicc[country][1] +=1
            elif country == i["country"] and i["medal"] == "bronze":
                dicc[country][2] +=1
return dicc

print(funct(athletes, "athletics men's 50000 metres"))
```

It works, but I'm just getting the info of the last athlete of that country (using the list from above):

`{'england': [0, 1, 0]`

When I should be getting (expected result):

`{'england': [1, 1, 0]`

what should I do to fix this?

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  Your posted code fails to run for various undefined symbols, and the output you cite is correct for the input you gave at the top.  We need to be able to reproduce your results from a simple cut & paste of your posted program.

Comment: Please post rest of the dictionary, or at least 3 different medals from the same country.

Comment: The problem is that the rest of the dictionary has 23k athletes, I could post more, but not the whole thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try following:

do not reset the counters of a country after every iteration:

```
def funct(athletes:list, event:str):
    import copy
    list1 = [0, 0, 0]
    dicc = {}
    for i in athletes:
        if i["event"] == event and i["medal"] != 'na':
            if i["country"] not in dicc: # only initialize if not existing
                dicc[i["country"]] = copy.deepcopy(list1)
        for country in dicc.keys():
            if country == i["country"] and i["medal"] == "gold":
                dicc[country][0] +=1
            elif country == i["country"] and i["medal"] == "silver":
                dicc[country][1] +=1
            elif country == i["country"] and i["medal"] == "bronze":
                dicc[country][2] +=1
return dicc

print(funct(athletes, "athletics men's 50000 metres"))
```